# How to apply DRY principle in Chrome and Edge Options

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
 private void initializeChromeDriver(String headlessMode) {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(headlessMode)) {
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080");
        }
        webDriverThreadLocal.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
    }

    private void initializeEdgeDriver(String headlessMode) {
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        edgeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(headlessMode)) {
            edgeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080");
        }
        webDriverThreadLocal.set(new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions));
    }
```

I have these similar functions where am repeating the code and calling these two below

```
 private void initializeWebDriver() {
        Properties prop = GenericUtils.getDataFromPropertyFile("global");
        String headlessMode = System.getProperty("headless", prop.getProperty("headless", "false"));
        String browser = System.getProperty("browser", prop.getProperty("browser", "chrome"));

        switch (browser.toLowerCase()) {
            case "chrome":
                initializeChromeDriver(headlessMode);
                break;
            case "edge":
                initializeEdgeDriver(headlessMode);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported browser: " + browser);
        }

        getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

How can i avoid repitition in options class code?

unable to think how to proceed